# 2002 Ford Escape Alternator Removal. Haynes says you can just remove it from the bottom but I know you cant?

Tags: ford, alternator, escape

I've taken out the alternator on this car twice. Both times I tied a rope to it and pulled it out from the top (damaging the wiring harness and probably some other stuff in the process). A mechanic told me you are supposed to remove the passenger side motor mount and jack up the engine and then you will have enough room to remove it from the bottom.

I'm following a Haynes manual right now and it says nothing about jacking up the engine. It just says you unbolt it and remove it which I know for a fact is misinformation. I can't help but wonder what else they might have messed up.

Is there any chance Haynes is right and you can just remove it from the bottom? Yes, I am looking at the right year and engine size in the Haynes manual.

Comment: Is this a 4-cyl or the 6-cyl?

Comment: 6 cylinders of raw power.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I've removed the alternator on a 4-cylinder (twice ... in fact three times if you count the time I changed the clutch out, which requires the entire engine to get pulled, which includes the alternator - and this wasn't even my Escape! :o) ). It isn't hard, but there's a trick to it. I understood the only way to get the 6-cyl out is by taking the passenger side wheel off and removing the inner fender well, along with lifting the engine. I guess you've found a new way?

Comment: You know, when you go to a mechanic and they quote a job, they're going to the AllData or Mitchell's database, which lists "normal" time for an expert to do that job by the book, for each model and year of car. That data will reflect the task duration, and it's not guesswork, they are following the *factory* shop manual which proscribes the Ford-approved method.  Which is mindful of things like wiring harness damage.

Comment: I can't take credit for it. I saw it on a YouTube video. I can't remember which one specifically. Maybe this one https://youtu.be/5BLOD9gSheM. It's no fun that's for sure.